# Show that if $\mathbb{E}X_n = 0$ and $\sup\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{E}|X_n|^4 \leq C$ then $\frac{1}{n} (X_1+\dots+X_n) \to 0$ almost surely

Tags: probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems

Suppose $\{X_n\}_{n=1}^{+\infty}$ is a sequence of independent variables.

I'm trying to prove that if $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}: \mathbb{E}X_n = 0$ and $\exists C\in \mathbb{R}: \sup\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{E}|X_n|^4 \leq C$, then $\frac{1}{n} (X_1+X_2+\dots+X_n) \to 0$ almost surely.

First, my question is, is that true that the second premise $\sup\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{E}|X_n|^4 \leq C$ is equivalent to this: $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}: \mathbb{E}|X_n|^4 \leq C$?

I was trying to apply [Kolmogorov's strong law](https://www.math.ust.hk/%7Emakchen/MATH5411/Chap1Sec7.pdf). For this, I have to prove that this series converges:
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty} \dfrac{\text{Var}(X_n)}{n^2}$$

How can I approach this problem? I would appreciate any help.

Comment: You can show that $\sup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} Var(X_n)$ is bounded.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven I'm not sure how $Var(X_n)$ can be bounded by  $\mathbb{E}|X_n|^4$. And is that true that the second premise $\sup\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{E}|X_n|^4 \leq C$ is equivalent to this: $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}: \mathbb{E}X_n^4 \leq C$?

Comment: Yes, your premise is correct. To bound the variance you can use Hölder's inequality.

Comment: Might be useful to note that $Var(X_n)= \mathbb{E}[X_n^2]$ as $\mathbb{E}[X_n]=0$.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kolmogorov's strong law is overkill in this scenario. Let $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$. Then, since $\mathbb E[X_i] = 0$ for all $i$,

$$\mathbb E[S_n^4] = \sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb E[X_i^4] + 2\sum_{1\le i<j\le n}\mathbb E[X_i^2]\mathbb E[X_j^2] \le nC + n(n-1)C = n^2C,$$

where the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality is used to bound the second sum.
Hence using Chebyshev's inequality, for any $\varepsilon>0$ one has

$$ \mathbb P\left(\left|\frac1nS_n\right|>\varepsilon\right) \le \frac{\mathbb E[S_n^4]}{n^4\epsilon^4} \le \frac{C}{n^2\epsilon^4}. $$

It follows that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb P\left(\left|\frac1nS_n\right|>\varepsilon\right) < \infty$, and so by Borel-Cantelli we have that $\left|\frac1nS_n\right|>\varepsilon$ only finitely many times, with probability one. Since this is true for any $\varepsilon>0$, it follows that $\frac1nS_n\to0$ almost surely.